# Select2 huge data blocking render

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 js multiple choice box. Retrieving data by ajax post method. While data is loading its blocking render. I tried some solutions but couldnt find one. Any helps will be useful. Thank you.

Here is my code ;

```
function projectSearchOptions() {
    let element = $('#projectSearch')
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API_URL + 'getMatters',
        async: true,
    }).then(function (data) {
        for (var d = 0; d < data.data.length; d++) {
            var option = new Option(data.data[d].name, data.data[d].id, false, false);

            element.select2().append(option);
        }
        element.select2({
            placeholder: "Search",
            closeOnSelect:false,
        }).trigger('change');
    });
}
```

Comment: Just remove `async: true,` maybe?

Comment: this makes everything worse. Entire browser is blocking instead of div